# Xcode - Help implementing some code into a view based app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, ios4

Can someone help me with implementing this code into a view based app?

This is the code that I have:

```
- (void)webViewUIWebView *)newsweb didFailLoadWithErrorNSError *)error {
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Error1!"       message:@"Please confirm network connectivity and try again!" delegate:self     cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [alert show];
   [alert release];
}
```

With this code and any other code that I may need, but don't know, I would like to know what code to implement into the .h + .m view controller files.

What I am trying to achieve is an error after starting the app if there is no network connection available. What I'm worried about also but not quite sure if it will happen, is that this will repeat the error "x" times for how many UIViews I have. If that would be the case could you also help me should that it would only show the error once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a Boolean in your header file, and when the alert fires, change it. If the Boolean is false, then simply don't show the alert.

```
@interface
    BOOL alertShown;
@end
```

```
@implementation
    -(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching{
           alertShown = NO;
}

    -(void)webViewError{
          if(alertShown == NO){
              //show the alert
              alertShown = YES;
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm still a bit unsure about something. I have implemented the code that you have given me, and it runs fine but obviously it doesn't do anything. I am assuming that I still have to implement the original code that I showed in the question somewhere? But I don't know where.

Comment: In the if statement, add the code that creates and shows the alert. This way, the alert is only being created and shown if the app has not shown it before.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have got a very simple error now. - It says: "Expected identifier or '(' before '{' token."

Comment: OK so I have got it to run but it doesn't give an error when theres no network connection. (I turned airport off before running it in simulator).